# VBA Command Button - Copy and Paste Column with Column Name Match

Tags: excel, copy, paste, vba

Completely new to VBA here; so apologies if this was answered somewhere else or seems excruciatingly easy - I have looked and can't find any examples that line up with what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have an ActiveX command button that when clicked I would like it to copy data from C18:C123 to the corresponding column that has the matching header name from the copied data (C17) pasting *values and source formatting*. Essentially, I don't want to copy the data until the "Update" command button is clicked, and it needs to be able to match the location of the data being pasted to the name of the source of the data in C17. This is also copying and pasting on the same sheet in the same workbook.

Note: The data I am dealing with is sensitive in nature and I couldn't provide a working example, but could create a separate sheet that exemplifies this problem if need be.

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried and explain specifically where you are stuck.  As is this question is too broad for this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the activeX button,click on view code and paste the following code there

```
'This is the location of all the headers one of which is the header in C17
Set lookup_rng = Range("H17:Q17")  

For Each cell In lookup_rng
    If cell.Value = Range("C17").Value Then
        Range("C18:C123").Copy
        cell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: This does everything I was asking; the only exception being that it copies and pastes the cell references that exist in C17:C123, how can I get it to copy the values and source formatting only?

Comment: @Connor Hogan Edited